# Swipe to Delete on a UITableViewCell: cell gets squished

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, editing

I have a custom tableview cell created programmatically that consists of: a background view with an image 3 labels on the left and hand side one UISwitch on the right hand side. I want to be able to swipe and delete the cell. This works, however, when I swipe to bring up the delete button, the delete button pushes the background view (along with everything else) over as if it's squishing the cell. How do I get it so that the background image doesn't shrink?

I've searched around for this problem and some people said it had to do with autoresizing masks, but that didn't seem to affect anything. I also don't want to manually set the width of the cell in the layoutSubviews method as I saw one suggestion had.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem, I'm guessing (since you didn't post any code), is that you added all of these UI Elements as subviews of the cell, i.e. cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor someColor], [cell addSubview:label1], etc etc.

Here's the thing: A cell's view doesn't know how to resize itself appropriately when things like editing mode occur. However, a cell's contentView, which is a UIView, DOES know how to resize. For this reason, you need to add your labels, switches, etc. as subviews of the contentView, not the cell. Doing this will resize everything appropriately when you enter editing mode.

Comment: +1 for correct answer. One addition though, the content within the cell needs to be setup with the correct autoresizingMask.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Sorry for not posting code but it seemed like too much to post as I didn't know where the problem was. I actually am adding to the contentView, so is it a autoresizing mask issue? For instance, for the background view image, what should the mask be set to?

Comment: Even though I was already doing it, I marked your answer as correct. The problem was actually because it WAS auto adjusting. Instead of setting the background view I created a new subview to act as the background view.

Answer (score 4):

I just resolved the similar problem. **It has nothing to do with the content view**. When you added a UIImageView to a cell, either in interface builder, or storyboard, it has all springs and struts set. You will notice that your UILabels only have top and left strut set.

**Removing inner springs and right/bottom strut for a UIImageView on a UITableView cell would prevent them from being squished by the swipe to delete button.**

[image: UItableview cell squishes uiimage fix]

Comment: This solution is much more easier than the previous one! Thanks!